# Show a preloaded canvas image when an element is selected

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can preload some images and draw them in a canvas, following this tutorial:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/

I want to show a base image in the canvas by default, and then draw the other images only when a user clicks on a specific list item. Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/xz1x8jkr/

```
document.querySelector("highlight_1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  ctx.drawImage(images.arrow45, 177, 464, 32, 32);
});
```

I can't get this bit working and would really appreciate some advice. Thanks!

UPDATE TO QUESTION

Thanks to Monica Olejniczak I have gotten further with this, but am stuck again.

In the sources array I want to pull in the value for 'base' by using getElementById() and targeting the source URL of the image on the web page with the id of "canvasBase"

Here is my updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xz1x8jkr/21/

Can (something like) this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click handler isn't firing because your selector refers to the tag `<highlight_1>`, which does not exist. This should instead be `.highlight_1` to specify the class for `<li class="highlight_1">`.

Another reason this snippet of code isn't working as expected is due to the fact that you are trying to reference the variable `images`. However, this variable is only declared in the callback to load the source images as demonstrated below.

```
loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    // Reference to images is available in this function, and any nested functions.
    ctx.drawImage(images.base, 0, 0, 685, 525);
});

// Images reference no longer available here

document.querySelector("highlight_1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Images reference is also no longer available here 
    ctx.drawImage(images.arrow45, 177, 464, 32, 32);
});
```

Instead, you should have something like the following:

```
loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    ctx.drawImage(images.base, 0, 0, 685, 525);
    document.querySelector(".highlight_1").addEventListener("click", function() {
       ctx.drawImage(images.arrow45, 177, 464, 32, 32);
    });
});
```

This way you can access `images` as it references the declaration specified in the `loadImages` callback.

Comment: Thank you so much, such silly errors on my part! How would you go about allowing the user to "turn off" the image by clicking on the same list item once more?

Comment: I'd do something like this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xz1x8jkr/7/). Basically keep a track of all the items you want rendered (by adding and removing from the items array), then render when necessary. Consider using classes and a requestAnimationFrame for this approach.